# is there multikey index and compound index in hbase?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, hbase

I 'm familiar with mongodb.

you know, there are many index types in mongodb, such as:

multikey index : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/
, which is very useful for keyword search, I ever used it to build a simple search engine.

compound index is also very useful in mongodb : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/  which is used for multi fields' query.

but I need to migrate my database from mongodb to hbase, do you know some similar index in hbase which can realize the same function with multikey and compound index in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBase doesn't support secondary indexes, that's one of the trade-offs in order to be able to scale to massive data sets. These are the options you have:
http://hbase.apache.org/book/secondary.indexes.html

It all depends on the amount of data you're going to handle and your access patterns. For me, both dual writing to "index" tables & summary tables are the best approaches, just keep in mind that this has to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of indexing in HBase as of now. I know there is some demand within the community for Indexing. But there are other projects which provide indexing on  top of Hbase, One particular one i looked at was [Huawei Hindex](https://github.com/Huawei-Hadoop/hindex)